# java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: no such algorithm: SHA256WITHRSA for provider BC

Tags: java, bouncycastle, pkcs#7

I'm using bouncycastle v161
I try verifying PKCS#7 Signature by this following code:

```
 private static boolean verifySign(String sP7sData, String sReqData, String sCertPath){
 boolean bVerify = false;
 CMSProcessable data = new CMSProcessableByteArray(sReqData.getBytes());
 CMSSignedData csData = new CMSSignedData(signedData);
 CMSProcessableByteArray cspByteArray = (CMSProcessableByteArray) csData.getSignedContent();
 byte[] dataInCMS = (byte[]) cspByteArray.getContent();
 SignerInformationStore signers = csData.getSignerInfos();
 Iterator it = signers.getSigners().iterator();
 while(it.hasNext()){
     SignerInformation signer = (SignerInformation) it.next();
     bVerify = signer.verify((new JcaSimpleSignerInfoVerifierBuilder().setProvider("BC").build((X509Certificate)cert)));
     if (bVerify) {
         System.out.println("Verify!!!");
         break;
     }
 }
 }
```

but it prompt following message when run:

```
org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSException: can't create digest calculator: exception on setup:     java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: no
 such algorithm: SHA256WITHRSA for provider BC
        at org.bouncycastle.cms.SignerInformation.doVerify(Unknown Source)
        at org.bouncycastle.cms.SignerInformation.verify(Unknown Source)
        at Main.verifySign(Main.java:205)
        at Main.main(Main.java:126)
Caused by: org.bouncycastle.operator.OperatorCreationException: exception on setup:      java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: no such algorithm: SHA256WITHRSA for provider BC
        at org.bouncycastle.operator.jcajce.JcaDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder$1.get(Unknown Source)
        at org.bouncycastle.cms.SignerInformationVerifier.getDigestCalculator(Unknown Source)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: no such algorithm: SHA256WITHRSA for provider BC  
       at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getService(GetInstance.java:87)
       at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:206)
       at java.security.Security.getImpl(Security.java:698)
       at java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance(MessageDigest.java:227)
       at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.util.NamedJcaJceHelper.createDigest(Unknown Source)
       at org.bouncycastle.operator.jcajce.OperatorHelper.createDigest(Unknown Source)
    ... 6 more
```

What I'm wrong? This is my first time to handle pkcs#7 format signed message.

Comment: what is the java version you are using ? please mention with patch level details

Comment: i am using jdk1.8.0_144.

Comment: any sloutions? @stockton